# Facing an issue while loading the Instagram URL in Android webview

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I'm trying to show Instagram account page in the app using webview. Please note that, for some reason I don't want to redirect/open it in the browser. Also, if user logged in to follow that account then I want to keep him logged in for future use. So I've used setAppCachePath & setDatabasePath. Instagram homepage loads and login works fine but when I'm trying to open the account page, I'm getting an error. Please check,

Source Code:

```
    web_view = findViewById(R.id.web_view_insta);
    web_view.requestFocus();
    web_view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web_view.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    web_view.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
    web_view.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    web_view.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    web_view.getSettings().setAppCachePath(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/cache");
    web_view.getSettings().setDatabasePath(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/databases");
    web_view.loadUrl("https://www.instagram.com/_insta_account_id_/");
```

Error Log:

```
08-20 20:56:11.908 I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(11)] "SyntaxError: Invalid flags supplied to RegExp constructor 'u'", source: https://www.instagram.com/static/bundles/metro/Vendor.js/5a56d51ae30f.js (11)
08-20 20:56:11.910 I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(262)] "Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Invalid flags supplied to RegExp constructor 'u'", source: https://www.instagram.com/static/bundles/metro/Consumer.js/941d0bc776e6.js (262)
```

I tried:

```
web_view.loadUrl("https://www.instagram.com/_u/_insta_account_id_/");
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I solved by adding user agent - `web_view.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Android");`